# How create separate component for prev/next buttons ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, button, jsx

I created a simple application using ReactJS. This app is the profiles list, where for simplicity when displaying a profile I only show the name.
I added buttons to display the previous and next profiles, but I did it very simple way and inside the main component.

My questions:

1. how to separate this buttons from a separate component
2. how I can improve the "toggle" functions for these buttons

```js
// my profiles.json
let profiles = [{"name":"John"}, {"name":"Kitty"}, {"name":"Ji"}, {"name":"Mattis"}]

class Profile extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      index: 1,
      disabledNext: false,
      disabledPrev: false
    }
  }
  togglePrev(e) {
    let index = this.state.index - 1
    let disabledPrev = false
    if (index <= 0) {
      e.preventDefault()
      index = 0
      disabledPrev = true
    }

    this.setState({ index: index, disabledPrev: disabledPrev, disabledNext: false })
  }

  toggleNext(e) {
    let index = this.state.index + 1
    let disabledNext = false
    if (index === this.props.profiles.length - 1) {
      e.preventDefault()
      index = this.props.profiles.length - 1
      disabledNext = true
    }

    this.setState({ index: index, disabledNext: disabledNext, disabledPrev: false })
  }
  render() {
    const { index, disabledNext, disabledPrev } = this.state
    const profile = this.props.profiles ? this.props.profiles[index] : null
    if (profile) {
      return (
       <div className='profile'>
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.togglePrev.bind(this)} disabled={disabledPrev}>Prev</button>
            <button onClick={this.toggleNext.bind(this)} disabled={disabledNext}>Next</button>
          </div>
          <Profile {...profile} />
       </div>
      )
    } else {
      return <span>error</span>
    }
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Main profiles={profiles} />
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Herasimenak, so basically you just want to modulate your prev/next button in specifics React Class components that it ?

Comment: basically I think there is two subjects which interest you right now, the Lifting State Up  concept and the Refs element, all from Reactjs core library. 
It is all about data flow so I let you dive in the river. Later when you'll build more complex applications redux will come at hand for your needs. Good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Question 1**

To answer your first question I just made two very simple [functional components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components)  called Prev and Next. They get rendered within the Main component's render function (where the old buttons were). As you can see, the appropriate functions and values are passed as props.

**Question 2**

As you can see, most of the code has been stripped from these functions. To determine if the button should be enabled or disabled I used [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_()) and [strict inequality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Non-identity_strict_inequality_(!)). That's based on the index being the minimum (0) or maximum value (number of elements in the array).

I also transformed the Profile component to a functional component, just for kicks.

Hope this helps!

```js
// my profiles.json
let profiles = [{"name":"John"}, {"name":"Kitty"}, {"name":"Ji"}, {"name":"Mattis"}]

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      index: 1,
      disabledNext: false,
      disabledPrev: false
    }
  }

  togglePrev(e) {
    let index = this.state.index - 1;
    let disabledPrev = (index === 0);

    this.setState({ index: index, disabledPrev: disabledPrev, disabledNext: false })
  }

   toggleNext(e) {
     let index = this.state.index + 1;
     let disabledNext = index === (this.props.profiles.length - 1);

     this.setState({ index: index, disabledNext: disabledNext, disabledPrev: false })
   }

   render() {
     const { index, disabledNext, disabledPrev } = this.state
     const profile = this.props.profiles ? this.props.profiles[index] : null
     
     if (profile) {
       return (
         <div className='profile'>
           <div>
             <Prev toggle={(e) => this.togglePrev(e)} active={disabledPrev} />
             <Next toggle={(e) => this.toggleNext(e)} active={disabledNext} />
           </div>
           <Profile {...profile} />
         </div>
       )
     } else {
       return <span>error</span>
     }
  }
}

function Prev(props) {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.toggle} disabled={props.active}>Previous</button>
  );
}

function Next(props) {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.toggle} disabled={props.active}>Next</button>
  );
}

function Profile(props) {
  return (
    <div>
       <h1>{props.name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Main profiles={profiles} />
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```